# How to create diagonal matrix with an aligned diagonal?

Tags: math-mode, matrices

How do I display truly diagonal matrices? I want to have a diagonal bloc matrix. The solution below has several problems : the diagonal terms aren't really aligned in the first half, and the diagonal dots `\ddots` aren't steep enough between the zeros in the second half.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
    \mathrm{Mat}(u;\mathcal{B})=
    \begin{pmatrix}
        I_{n_+}\\&-I_{n_-}\\
        &&R_{\theta_1}\\
        &&&R_{\theta_2}\\
        &&&&\ddots\\
        &&&&&R_{\theta_r}\\
        &&&&&&0\\
        &&&&&&&0\\
        &&&&&&&&\ddots\\
        &&&&&&&&&0\\
    \end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Sebastiano Please never ever remove such spaces, this will bereave us of any possibility to revert the \\ corruption !!!!!

Comment: @samcarter Ok. I like the order and I thought that eliminating the spaces does not affect the correct compilation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Mat}{Mat}
\newcommand{\diagentry}[1]{\mathmakebox[1.8em]{#1}}
\newcommand{\xddots}{%
  \raise 4pt \hbox {.}
  \mkern 6mu
  \raise 1pt \hbox {.}
  \mkern 6mu
  \raise -2pt \hbox {.}
}
\begin{document}
\[
\Mat(u;\mathcal{B})=
\begin{pmatrix}
    \diagentry{I_{n_+}}\\
    &\diagentry{-I_{n_-}}\\
    &&\diagentry{R_{\theta_1}}\\
    &&&\diagentry{R_{\theta_2}}\\
    &&&&\diagentry{\xddots}\\
    &&&&&\diagentry{R_{\theta_r}}\\
    &&&&&&\diagentry{0}\\
    &&&&&&&\diagentry{0}\\
    &&&&&&&&\diagentry{\xddots}\\
    &&&&&&&&&\diagentry{0}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

another one that puts the burden on the reader but saves his/her eyes in my opinion

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Mat}{Mat}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\diagfences}{(}{)}
\newcommand{\diag}{\operatorname{diag}\diagfences}
\begin{document}\noindent
I would instead do either 
\[
\Mat(u;\mathcal{B})=
\begin{pmatrix}
I_{n_+}\\
&\!\!-I_{n_-}\\
&&R_{\theta}\\
&&&0_m
\end{pmatrix},\;R_{\theta}=\diag{R_{\theta_1}, \cdots,R_{\theta_r}}
\]
or even
\[
\Mat(u;\mathcal{B})= \diag{I_{n_+},-I_{n_-},R_{\theta},0_m},\; R_{\theta}=\diag{R_{\theta_1}\, ,\, \cdots,R_{\theta_r}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

[image]

One possibility is to assert control and position the items at exactly a 45 degree slope (or whatever slope you want) by adjusting the coordinates:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\mathrm{Mat}(u;\mathcal{B})=
\begin{pmatrix}
I_{n_+}\\&-I_{n_-}\\
&&R_{\theta_1}\\
&&&R_{\theta_2}\\
&&&&\ddots\\
&&&&&R_{\theta_r}\\
&&&&&&0\\
&&&&&&&0\\
&&&&&&&&\ddots\\
&&&&&&&&&0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\[\setlength\unitlength{13pt}
\mathrm{Mat}(u;\mathcal{B})=
\left(\begin{picture}(11,6)(0,-5.5)
\put(1,-1){\makebox(0,0){$I_{n_+}$}}
\put(2,-2){\makebox(0,0){$-I_{n_-}$}}
\put(3,-3){\makebox(0,0){$R_{\theta_1}$}}
\put(4,-4){\makebox(0,0){$R_{\theta_2}$}}
%\put(5,-5){\makebox(0,0){$\ddots$}}
\put(4.8,-4.8){\makebox(0,0){$\cdot$}}
\put(5.1,-5.1){\makebox(0,0){$\cdot$}}
\put(5.4,-5.4){\makebox(0,0){$\cdot$}}
\put(6,-6){\makebox(0,0){$R_{\theta_r}$}}
\put(7,-7){\makebox(0,0){$0$}}
\put(8,-8){\makebox(0,0){$0$}}
%\put(9,-9){\makebox(0,0){$\ddots$}}
\put(8.8,-8.8){\makebox(0,0){$\cdot$}}
\put(9.1,-9.1){\makebox(0,0){$\cdot$}}
\put(9.4,-9.4){\makebox(0,0){$\cdot$}}
\put(10,-10){\makebox(0,0){$0$}}
\end{picture}
\right)
\]


\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for using a `picture` environment.

Comment: The second solution is pretty good. It seems a lot of code but nothing that can not be solved with a macro.

Comment: @OSjerick Yep, and I would have upvoted David's answer at the drop of a hat … if only it *did* use a macro for this ;)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of writing anything, simply leave the cell blank and `array` will take care of it. Here is the code

```latex
\begin{equation}
\rho _{\epsilon} = \left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
\epsilon &  &  &  &  \\
 & \epsilon &  &  &  \\
 &  & \ddots & &  \\
 &  &  & \epsilon &  \\
 &  &  &  & \epsilon \\
\end{array} \right)
\end{equation}
```

The result looks like

> [image: diagonal matrix]

Using environment `pmatrix` would be a great idea, but it is hard to take care of the spacing and alignment.

Answer (score 4):

Here I did 2 things to the OP's MWE.  I used a TABstack with `\fixTABwidth{T}` to auto set all column widths the same; and I designed an `\xddots` to be more diagonal.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,amsmath}
\TABstackMath
\fixTABwidth{T}
\newcommand\xddots{\stackunder[2.5pt]{\stackanchor[2.8pt]{\kern-14pt.}{.}}{\kern14pt.}}
\begin{document}
\[
\mathrm{Mat}(u;\mathcal{B})=
\parenMatrixstack{
I_{n_+}     &&&&&&&&&\\
&-I_{n_-}    &&&&&&&&\\
&&R_{\theta_1}&&&&&&&\\
&&&R_{\theta_2}&&&&&&\\
&&&&\xddots      &&&&&\\
&&&&&R_{\theta_r}&&&&\\
&&&&&&0           &&&\\
&&&&&&&0           &&\\
&&&&&&&&\xddots      &\\
&&&&&&&&&0
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`. The key `columns-width=auto` assures that all the columns will have the same width and then that the centers of cells on the diagonal are aligned (since you know that all the rows have the same height and depth). Then, I use the built-in command `\line` (available in the so-called `\CodeAfter`) which draws that dotted lines with Tikz (in fact, the sublayer of Tikz).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\[
    \mathrm{Mat}(u;\mathcal{B})=
    \begin{pNiceMatrix}[columns-width=auto,xdots/shorten = 2mm]
        I_{n_+}\\
        &-I_{n_-}\\
        &&R_{\theta_1}\\
        &&&R_{\theta_2}\\
        &&&&\\
        &&&&&R_{\theta_r}\\
        &&&&&&0\\
        &&&&&&&0\\
        &&&&&&&&\\
        &&&&&&&&&0\\
    \CodeAfter \line{4-4}{6-6} \line{8-8}{10-10}
    \end{pNiceMatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]